# Trying to combine INDEX and MATCH functions in VBA

Tags: function, vba, excel, worksheet-function

Why doesn't this work?

```
Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index((Range("CountryNames")), _
                Application.Match((Range("B61")), (Range("CurrencyValues")), 0))
```

Comment: Hi, did you enter the formula in a cell and verify that it returns the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Too many parentheses. Instead of passing a range to `Index`, you're only passing the range's *value.* That is OK for the arguments to `Match`, since that function works just as well on values as it does for ranges. But `Index` can only work with ranges. Try this instead:

```
Result = Application.Index(Range("CountryNames"), _
        Application.Match(Range("B61"), Range("CurrencyValues"), 0))
```